# not getting replace all ?' with empty string in java

Tags: java

I have a string like `ABCDEF?'JHUGY?'JHGH'GFTF'`

I want to replace all `?'` only with entry string.

Output should be like this

```
ABCDEFJHUGYJHGH'GFTF'
```

I've tried all combination like replace and replace all as well with but its not getting removed.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: "I've tried all combination like replace and replace all as well with but its not getting removed." - please provide a [mcve]. We can't tell what you're doing wrong if we can't see your code.

Comment: Did you escape the question mark?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `replaceAll` method of `String` class and and escape `?` in `regex`, e.g.:

```
String s = "ABCDEF?'JHUGY?'JHGH'GFTF'";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\?'", ""));
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) javadoc for `replaceAll` method.

Comment: Shouldn't the first sentence be "You can use an inappropriate method to replace the String and need to correct your search String, due to that bad choice"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex so don't use `replaceAll`:

```
result = input.replace("?'", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(new String("ABCDEF?'JHUGY?'JHGH'GFTF'").replaceAll("\\?",""));
     }
```

TRy this. You need to escape ? as it has special meaning in regex syntax.

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                String replacement)
```

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement

Comment: I don't get why people try to fix their patterns to match regex rules instead of just using `replace`. Would make too much sense?